# Hyperlink to go back to previous page in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page in asp .net `(http://localhost/error/pagenotfound).`

There is a link in page, on clicking on which has to go back to previous page  from where I came from.

```
<a href="#">Go Back to Previous Page.</a>
```

How can I go back to previous page by taking from history

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you can use this:

```
<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back to Previous Page</a>
```

Answer (score 32):

If you are using asp.net then remember that

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

and

```
window.history.back()
```

Both will take you to back page. 
But the previous page will not be exactly previous page.

### For example

Suppose you are on page `Default.aspx` and there is a `asp:button`
Now when you click on the button and you are back on `Default.aspx`
**in this situation your previous page is still you Default.aspx**

**Take another exapmle**

You have two pages `Default1.aspx` and `Default2.aspx`

**Condition 1**:- button clicked on `Default1.aspx` which redirect you to `Default2.aspx`
     ok your previous page is `Default1.aspx`

**Condition 2**:- button clicked on `Default1.aspx` and post back on the same `Default1.aspx` page

 Now your previous page is still `Default1.aspx`

---

**Edit**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if( !IsPostBack )
     {
        ViewState["RefUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     }
  }
```

and use this in back button as follows

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      object refUrl = ViewState["RefUrl"];
      if (refUrl != null)
          Response.Redirect((string)refUrl);
 }
```

Comment: Ya exactly any solution for this?

Comment: Yes put your previous page name in the view-state. Means you will have to save it some where for your use.

Comment: Edited my answer for your answer

Comment: Thanks, really the answer that is signed as the correct answer depend on js browser APIs which have an issue like you describe so i suggest for any one to use this approach instead of the first one

Comment: This answer has some limitations. Imagine there is a sequence of pages P1 -> P2 -> P3. With this approach, you cannot go backwards from P3 to initial page P1.

Comment: @nnunes10 If you want to do so you can add Array of URL in session and navigate accordingly. Above code is just to go to previous page. If you have that requirement add new question.

Answer (score 11):

For Going to previous page

**First Method**

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
```

**Second Method**

```
<a href="##" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;">Go back</a>
```

if we want to more than one step back then increase

```
For going 2 steps back history.go(-2)
For going 3 steps back history.go(-3)
For going 4 steps back history.go(-4)
and so on........
```

Answer (score 7):

use this code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function goBack()
      {
      window.history.back()
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="#" onclick="goBack()">Back</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Window.history.Back is going to the same landing page

Answer (score 5):

I found this example

```
<input type="button" value=" &lt;-- BACK " onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">
```

Just put this your page, it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You should add an attribute which is about onclick like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back(); return false;");
}

protected void yourButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Response.Write("Stackoverflow <br/>");
}
```

This is about using a button to go previous page, you can modify it according to your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Following the example of शेखर

I would suggest to do the following and avoid any cycle on the url while posting back.

```
string from = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
string here = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();

if(from != here)
    Session["page"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

On your button click

```
object refUrl = Session["page"];
if (refUrl != null)
    Response.Redirect((string)refUrl);
```

This will save always the PAGE you are coming from.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this all weekend and haven't found the answer I was looking for.  The problem is, after a postback history.go(-1);  will not go back to where you want to go - that is, the page that got you there (with any changes made).

Using  Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(); will reload the page you are going back to and you may be like me and not want to lose any changes that were made to the page.  Above Rizwan Gill in 2013 hit on the answer that you want to go back 2, 3 or 4 pages but he didn't give a good way to do it.

The best way to do this is actually to use a pop-up modal for  your page when it is called if your are writing the calling page but if you want to do it this way and have a back button you'll have to remember each postback and count them.

So, start with your hidden field (in your .aspx file) :

```
    <asp:hiddenfield id="fldPostbackCount"
        value="0" 
        runat="server"/>
```

Then increment the value with each postback (in your .aspx.vb file):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        fldPostbackCount.Value = 1
    Else
        fldPostbackCount.Value = Int32.Parse(fldPostbackCount.Value) + 1
    End If

End Sub  '  Page_Load()
```

(I'm sure the .cs people can handle the to C conversion on this)

Now back to your .aspx file  you have to have a history button:

```
    <a href="javascript:history.go(-<%: fldPostbackCount.Value %>)" title="Back to Previous Page">Back to Previous Page</a>
```

Comment: NOTE:  I essentially did something 'similar' as above, where I did a history.go(-1) if zero postbacks where made (on the current page), and did a history.go(-2) if one or more postbacks where made on the current page (ie by the user clicking a button with an AJAX call, etc).  And the logic to whether it was -1 or -2 was calculated in javascript (ie urlCountForBackButton = 2 was placed in the AJAX call success/error function)

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code just write this:

```
Response.Write("<script>history.go(-1);</script>");
```